# Find and ReplaceAll : To get Find Value in Attribute and Replace with Content using XSLT3.0

Tags: xslt-3.0

I would like to do Find and Replace using XSLT 3.0. When I have found the value from `TextStyle` element with attribute of `FONTSTYLE` value it should store in variables and replace with the text.

Found Pattern is : `<String ID="p1_w5" CONTENT="Human" HPOS="261.948" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font1"/>`

Replace Pattern Expect this : `<String ID="p1_w5" CONTENT="<bold>Human</bold>" HPOS="261.948" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font1"/>`

How do achieve my requirements using XSLT Find and Replace?

My Current Input XML File is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ALTO>
<STYLES>
<TextStyle ID="font1" FONTFAMILY="cambria" FONTSIZE="12.000" FONTSTYLE="bold"/>
<TextStyle ID="font2" FONTFAMILY="cambria" FONTSIZE="7.920" FONTSTYLE="sup"/>
<TextStyle ID="font3" FONTFAMILY="cambria" FONTSIZE="12.000" FONTSTYLE="it"/>
</STYLES>
<LAYOUT>
<TextBlock  ID="p1_b1" HPOS="83.6703" VPOS="75.8759" HEIGHT="10.6680" WIDTH="445.700">
<TextLine WIDTH="445.700" HEIGHT="10.6680" ID="p1_t1" HPOS="83.6703" VPOS="75.8759">
<String ID="p1_w1" CONTENT="Hie" HPOS="83.6703" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w2" CONTENT="org" HPOS="154.915" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w3" CONTENT="of" HPOS="228.005" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w4" CONTENT="the" HPOS="241.393" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w5" CONTENT="Human" HPOS="261.948" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font1"/>
<String ID="p1_w6" CONTENT="cell" HPOS="303.263" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w8" CONTENT="a" HPOS="354.900" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w9" CONTENT="CANCER" HPOS="363.965" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font3"/>
</TextLine>
</TextBlock>
</LAYOUT>
</ALTO>
```

Tried XSLT file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fnc="http://www.xsweet.org/2022/ext"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/|node()|*|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | * | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:param name="styletag1" select="TextStyle[@FONTSTYLE = 'sup']"/>
    <xsl:param name="styletag2" select="TextStyle[@FONTSTYLE = 'it']"/>
    <xsl:param name="styletag3" select="TextStyle[@FONTSTYLE = 'bold']"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/|node()|*|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | * | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LAYOUT/TextBlock/TextLine/String[$styletag1]">
        <xsl:message>Superscript Need to Replace All</xsl:message>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
  <xsl:key name="text-style" match="TextStyle/@FONTSTYLE" use="../@ID"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="String[key('text-style', @STYLEREFS)]/@CONTENT">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="'&lt;' || key('text-style', ../@STYLEREFS) || '>' || . || '&lt;/' || key('text-style', ../@STYLEREFS) || '>'"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

but of course the output is XML with entity references in the attribute value e.g.

```
<String ID="p1_w5" CONTENT="&lt;bold&gt;Human&lt;/bold&gt;" HPOS="261.948" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font1"/>
```

If you really want e.g. `CONTENT="<bold>Human</bold>"` then use a character map

```
  <xsl:output use-character-maps="m1"/>

  <xsl:character-map name="m1">
    <xsl:output-character character="&lt;" string="&lt;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&gt;" string="&gt;"/>
  </xsl:character-map>
```

Comment: I would like to change `<String ID="p1_w5" CONTENT="&lt;bold&gt;Human&lt;/bold&gt;" HPOS="261.948" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font1"/>` to `<bold>Human</bold>`. It means remove `<String...>` element and except only texts.

Comment: @Balaji, that seems like a new requirement you should try to adapt the solution you accepted to on your own, if that attempt doesn't work out ask a new question with the necessary details. `xsl:element name="{key('text-style', ../@STYLEREFS)}"` is your friend.

Comment: I have tried and not got the expected result and posted new question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75118536/change-the-name-of-the-element-with-find-and-replace>. Please advise.