# Change the Name of the element with Find and Replace

Tags: xslt

Using Find and Replace (XSLT), how to remove element and create new element.

Found Pattern is : `<String ID="p1_w5" CONTENT="Human" HPOS="261.948" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font1"/>`

Replace Pattern Expect this : `<b>Human</b>`.

Note `<bold>` is rename with `<b>` tag and `<superscript>` is renamed with `<sup>` as per HTML. How do achieve my requirements using XSLT?

My Current Input XML File is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ALTO>
<STYLES>
<TextStyle ID="font1" FONTFAMILY="cambria" FONTSIZE="12.000" FONTSTYLE="bold"/>
<TextStyle ID="font2" FONTFAMILY="cambria" FONTSIZE="7.920" FONTSTYLE="sup"/>
<TextStyle ID="font3" FONTFAMILY="cambria" FONTSIZE="12.000" FONTSTYLE="it"/>
</STYLES>
<LAYOUT>
<TextBlock  ID="p1_b1" HPOS="83.6703" VPOS="75.8759" HEIGHT="10.6680" WIDTH="445.700">
<TextLine WIDTH="445.700" HEIGHT="10.6680" ID="p1_t1" HPOS="83.6703" VPOS="75.8759">
<String ID="p1_w1" CONTENT="Hie" HPOS="83.6703" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w2" CONTENT="org" HPOS="154.915" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w3" CONTENT="of" HPOS="228.005" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w4" CONTENT="the" HPOS="241.393" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w5" CONTENT="Human" HPOS="261.948" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font1"/>
<String ID="p1_w6" CONTENT="cell" HPOS="303.263" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w8" CONTENT="a" HPOS="354.900" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w9" CONTENT="CANCER" HPOS="363.965" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font3"/>
</TextLine>
</TextBlock>
</LAYOUT>
</ALTO>
```

XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xhtml" use-character-maps="m1" indent="no"/>

      <xsl:character-map name="m1">
        <xsl:output-character character="&lt;" string="&lt;"/>
        <xsl:output-character character="&gt;" string="&gt;"/>
      </xsl:character-map>
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/|node()|*|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | * | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:param name="styletag1" select="TextStyle[@FONTSTYLE = 'superscript']"/>
    <xsl:param name="styletag2" select="TextStyle[@FONTSTYLE = 'it']"/>
    <xsl:param name="styletag3" select="TextStyle[@FONTSTYLE = 'bold']"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/|node()|*|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | * | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:key name="text-style" match="TextStyle/@FONTSTYLE" use="../@ID"/>
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="String[key('text-style', @STYLEREFS)]/@CONTENT">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="'&lt;' || key('text-style', ../@STYLEREFS) || '>' || . || '&lt;/' || key('text-style', ../@STYLEREFS) || '>'"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight adaption of the code in the answer to your previous question

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
  
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:key name="text-style" match="TextStyle" use="@ID"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

   <xsl:template match="String[key('text-style', @STYLEREFS)]">
     <xsl:variable name="replacement" as="node()*">
       <xsl:element name="{key('text-style', @STYLEREFS)/@FONTSTYLE}">{@CONTENT}</xsl:element>
     </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$replacement" mode="fix-html"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="fix-html" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template mode="fix-html" match="bold">
    <b>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
    </b>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ALTO>
<STYLES>
<TextStyle ID="font1" FONTFAMILY="cambria" FONTSIZE="12.000" FONTSTYLE="bold"/>
<TextStyle ID="font2" FONTFAMILY="cambria" FONTSIZE="7.920" FONTSTYLE="sup"/>
<TextStyle ID="font3" FONTFAMILY="cambria" FONTSIZE="12.000" FONTSTYLE="it"/>
</STYLES>
<LAYOUT>
<TextBlock  ID="p1_b1" HPOS="83.6703" VPOS="75.8759" HEIGHT="10.6680" WIDTH="445.700">
<TextLine WIDTH="445.700" HEIGHT="10.6680" ID="p1_t1" HPOS="83.6703" VPOS="75.8759">
<String ID="p1_w1" CONTENT="Hie" HPOS="83.6703" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w2" CONTENT="org" HPOS="154.915" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w3" CONTENT="of" HPOS="228.005" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w4" CONTENT="the" HPOS="241.393" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w5" CONTENT="Human" HPOS="261.948" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font1"/>
<String ID="p1_w6" CONTENT="cell" HPOS="303.263" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w8" CONTENT="a" HPOS="354.900" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font0"/>
<String ID="p1_w9" CONTENT="CANCER" HPOS="363.965" VPOS="75.8759" STYLEREFS="font3"/>
</TextLine>
</TextBlock>
</LAYOUT>
</ALTO>
```

into

```
<b>Human</b>
<it>CANCER</it>
```

so that should show how to replace the elements that reference a style.

I guess you will want to add further templates like

```
  <xsl:template mode="fix-html" match="it">
    <i>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
    </i>
  </xsl:template>
```

to transform/fix all those styles you have to corresponding, existing HTML elements.